# QGIS Qt5 крашится программа из примера

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgis

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]крашится программа при запуске из примера QGIS.

.pro файл:

```
QT       += core gui xml

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = qgis1
TEMPLATE = app

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

LIBS += -L/usr/lib/ -lqgis_core -lqgis_gui
LIBS += -L/usr/lib/qgis/plugins/ -lgdalprovider
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/qgis
DEFINES += GUI_EXPORT= CORE_EXPORT=

SOURCES +=  main.cpp
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <qgsapplication.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QgsApplication app(argc, argv, true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: И на чем конкретно она крашится? какой стек вызовов в этот момент?

Comment: VTT, добавил скриншот.

Comment: А библиотка qgis1 собралась без проблем? Вам стоит пересобрать ее с отладочными символами.

Comment: а qgis откуда взята?

Comment: Fat-Zer, из репозитория.VTT, собралась без проблем.

Comment: VTT, это не бибилиотека, это сам пример.

Comment: @VictorC, из родного или стороннего? с виду похоже на какую-то несовместимость библиотек... ЗЫ: упоминать лучше с собакой — без неё нет уведомлений...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я устанавливал его через synaptic.

Comment: @VictorC, а без `-lgdalprovider` пробовал линковать? не похоже. что плагины предназначены для прямой линковки...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, пробовал.

Comment: гм... идеи заканчиваются... из оставшегося я бы предложил запустить под нормальным `gdb`, чтобы посмотреть полноценный backtrace и удостовериться, при загрузке какой именно библиотеки происходит креш....

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите примеры здесь: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Code-Examples

---

*P.S. Я не уверен, но мне кажется, что возникновение ошибки связано с отсутствием каких-то настроек/входных данных, которые должны были бы быть переданы инстансу приложения извне.*